# How to change ui text position?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this script attached to a cube :

I want to be able to change the ui text textName position.
The problem is in the Update I'm setting the textName position because I want the text to be above the object but then I can't change the textName position in other places in the code like in the Start.

Before all that the script was attached to a child object of the Cube so I could change the child position and the text was moving with the child object but because I also want to use OnTriggerEvent I moved the script to the Cube it self the parent and now the text is in the middle of the cube and not above it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
public class Rotations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textName;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public bool rotateText = false;
    public string textToDisplay;
    public float displayCurrentRotationSpeed;
 
    public bool easeInOut = false;
    public float rotationDuration;
    public float startAngle;
    public float stopAngle;
    public AnimationCurve curve;
 
    private float currentRotationTime;
 
    private void Start()
    {
        textName.text = textToDisplay;
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 namePos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position);
        textName.transform.position = namePos;
 
        if(rotateText)
        {
            displayCurrentRotationSpeed = rotationSpeed * currentRotationTime;
 
            if (easeInOut)
            {
 
                currentRotationTime += Time.deltaTime;
                var progress = curve.Evaluate(currentRotationTime / rotationDuration);
                var currentAngle = startAngle + (stopAngle - startAngle) * progress;
                textName.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, currentAngle, 0f);
            }
            else
            {
                if (displayCurrentRotationSpeed < 3f)
                {
                    currentRotationTime += Time.deltaTime;
                    textName.transform.Rotate(0, displayCurrentRotationSpeed, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    textName.transform.Rotate(0, displayCurrentRotationSpeed, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you wrote this in a big of a hurry. Some letters are missing (I'm assuming "Ho to change" should be "How" and "then I can change" should be "can't"?) and the description reads as rushed and unclear. Please take the time to edit your post and explain what you want step by step in detail. Explain how the behaviour you want differs from the current behaviour with this code.

Comment: thanks fixed the missig letters and I will add some screenshots to explain too.

Comment: You'd better always change the position in one place.